# rangeOfComposedCharacterSequenceAtIndex in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, string, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to port the [iosMath LaTeX library](https://github.com/kostub/iosMath) to C#. iosMath uses NSString's rangeOfComposedCharacterSequenceAtIndex in certain places. But I can't find any equivalent in [Xamarin's NSString API](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Foundation.NSString/). What am I missing? Is this functionality available some other way? If so, how?

Cross-posted on the Xamarin forums [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/111385/rangeofcomposedcharactersequenceatindex#latest).

Answer (score 0):

> Is this functionality available some other way?

We have to implement it by ourselves using C# if the api can not be found in the Class.

#### For example :

`rangeOfString` in `NSString` also can't be found ,and we can create the method instead.

```
static NSRange CalcRangeFor (string source, string substring)
{
    var range = new NSRange {
        Location = source.IndexOf (substring),
        Length = substring.Length
    };
    return range;
}
```

However, `rangeOfComposedCharacterSequenceAtIndex` is a bit of complex, you can search the [source code](https://github.com/apportable/Foundation/blob/master/System/Foundation/src/NSString.m#L1205) and implement with your new method. But I'm afraid it is still hard to do the work, since it is related to CoreFoundtion and we know little about it.

So why didn't you try to create a binding project? You don't have to transform the code from objective-c to c# but need some extra works for binding.

Refer to [Binding iOS Libraries](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/)